# twitter style updates

Tags: jquery, css

How to create this effect where it looks like a newly inserted update shows up at the top of the stack and pushed the rest down? This is how it is done at the twitter home page.

Update.

In case this isn't clear, I am trying to understand the whole effect of how the uipdates section is animated and updated with the smooth scrolling effect, including the animation.

Answer (score 4):

The following code should give you an idea of how it could be done.

```
var container = $("#tweetContainer"),
    speed = 250;

$("<div class='tweet'>1 new tweet</div>")
    .hide()
    .prependTo(container)
    .show(speed);

container.children(".tweet")
    .eq(-1)
    .hide(speed, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, how is the animation done and how is the stack re-ordered (the first item inserted, last one out) etc. I am looking at this..which could be a solution. http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list

Comment: Your question did not mention animation.

Comment: Thanks for the help.My original post clearly specifies.."this effect where it looks like a newly inserted update shows up at the top of the stack and pushed the rest down?", I would think that would be enough to indicate I am not looking for how to do a simple .append() in jquery, pls read the http://api.jquery.com/append/ documenation, it says nothing about pushing other elements out of a visible stack.

Comment: 1st: I suggested `prepend()`. 2nd: there is no "stack". 3rd: There is no `$(data).prependDataToAndRemoveLastChildFrom(container)`-like method in jQuery (you can make it a plugin if you want). Basically, if you want to receive carefully thought-out answers here on S.O., submit carefully thought-out questions/comments. We love to help out when we can; please be thoughtful and thankful for the free knowledge & advice.

Comment: Help certainly appreciated, but the question mentioned a live "example" I am not sure how much more "specific" one can get, I think that is plenty specific.